# Android crashes in a Bak BK-NB711G

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, screen, boot, crashes

I have a netbook device running Android, Gingerbread 2.3.x, but it does not load.

Upon boot-up, it is forever stuck on the familiar splash screen with Android written on it.

Can someone help me?

**Edit**: I have taken the liberty in editing this question, the device in question comes from [this site](http://www.bakinternational.com/detalhe.php?produto=500&categoria=90)

Comment: That looks like it's frozen during boot (rather than crashed). Can you boot into recovery? If so, can you delete cache from there, and try booting again? A last ressort (requiring you to boot into recovery as well) is to factory-reset the device (beware that this will also delete your apps and data from that device).

Comment: More than likely its stuck in a boot-loop for whatever reason - what was the last app you installed prior to this issue?

Comment: @t0mm13b I did installed nothing, it happened after some time of use. Thanks, by the way, I had forgot to put any kind of referring to the device. '^_^

Comment: Can you run `adb logcat` with USB plugged into netbook from another computer?

Comment: I'll try connecting the netbook to my pc. What should appear in the screen if something's wrong?

Comment: @bluefirebolt You already know something's wrong. The log output might help us work out *what's* wrong.

Comment: @DanHulme I think he's asking what sort of messages to expect.